# Is there a way to monitor socket buffer size of a running application under Windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, buffer

I am trying to guess what the size is used for UDP input socket of a running application and couldn't find any piece of software able to do it.
The closer Ifound is TracePlus/Winsock but it only works with 32bits applications and mine is 64bits...

Comment: TracePlus works with 32bit apps, and you have a 32bit app, so what is the problem?  Or did you mean you have a 64bit app instead?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to guess what buffer sizes the app is actually using in its code, I would suggest you instead use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to see the actual size of the packets that are actually being transmitted over the wire.  The app has to be using buffer sizes that are at least at large as the packets, or else WinSock would report `WSAEMSGSIZE` errors and data would get truncated/discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied using hooking techniques?I think detours can help you

Answer (score 0):

getsockopt() with the SO_RCVBUF option gives you the size of your socket receive buffer. Not sure that's whzt you really want though.